# (buying advice) external touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I often work on a dock and would still like to use the multi touch gestures but can't find an external touchpad except the one from Apple.

Can you suggest me good devices?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that Apple have nailed and other companies seem to simply *do not* get -- trackpads and HiDPI displays. Apple trackpads are by far the best of anything commercially available. I've bought one myself and I'm enjoying the experience -- simply top-notch

Comment: in conjunction with elementaryos? not sure if this works outside the apple ecosystem

Comment: well ... working on a dock ... i assume with a laptop ... how about bringing the laptop to an apple store and asking to try before you buy ?

Comment: @Tealk yes, it will work, because I am using it right this instance. The Linux kernel has a working Apple Magic Trackpad 2 driver

Answer (score 0):

I asked elementary guys the same question on Twitter and the answer looks the same: in the demo where they show the new gestures, **they use an Apple Magic Trackpad 2**. I will probably buy one soon. I just wait a confirmation that it works easily with elementary.
The discussion is here: https://twitter.com/nathanaelh/status/1425397957772423171